# Cloud Translation API translate - option for alternate translation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

i seek a solution (option?) for activate the alternate translation in google cloud tranlate api.
The online version of google translate offer that option, and display alternative sentences.
Any option for activate this feature in the API?

[image: alternate sentences]

Comment: Are you referring to [AutoML Translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/automl/docs/) displaying alternate translations in Translation AI?  [Translation AI](https://cloud.google.com/translate) offers the option of AutoML Translation and Translation API, In [Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs) there is no option of doing translation using console and it’s possible only using Rest API and the client libraries. Whereas AutoML Translation has the option of translating using console, but it doesn’t have the option of displaying alternate translations.

Comment: If you want the feature of displaying alternate translations in Translation AI to be enabled, you can open a new feature request on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your requirement.